# count unique values that start with specific criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, countif

from Data column like to see how many unique values i have starting with CC (=3)

```
AB0010
CC0009
AB0010
EF0011
CC1001
AB0090
CC1001
(empty field)
CC1001
CC2001
```

Start with:

```
AB = 2
CC = 3
EF = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT($A$1:$A$10,2)=D1,1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,D1&"*")))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode. If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]